# How to get Aspect working on all getters in Pojo

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspectj

I am aiming to do some updates for all getters in Pojo by using Aspect and Spring AOP. I would like to do something like I can get "haha" + Str when I do the getter.

Here is my Aspect:

```java
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class GetterAspect {
  @Before("execution(* com.docusign.docusign.dto.AspectPojo.getName())")
  public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    log.info(" Check before pojo");
    log.info("", joinPoint);
  }
}
```

Here is my Pojo:

```java
@Data
public class AspectPojo {
  private String name;
  private String email;
}
```

Here is my test ctrl:

```java
@GetMapping
public AspectPojo get() {
  AspectPojo pojo = aspectManager.getPojo();
  log.info(pojo.getName());
  return pojo;
}
```

I can't get the pointcut triggered, I'd appreciate if anyone can help out.

Comment: Why do you add `@Configuration` to your `@Aspect`? You should add `@Component` instead and then have a separate configuration class where you configure Spring the way you need it, e.g. `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, `@ComponentScan` etc. Furthermore, Alexey's answer + my comment there apply. Please also note that your sample code does not constitute an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so please edit it in order to create one.

Comment: One more thing: You cannot manipulate a method's return value from a `@Before` advice, you ought to use `@Around`. Maybe reading the Spring manual first before trying to use AOP would be advisable.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will need to have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring AOP support not all feature of AspectJ standard. How I remember only public methods of Spring beans could be handled by Spring AOP. If your getters are in `@Controller`, `@Component` or `@Service` annotated class it will be handled but for example JPA entities cannot be handled this way.

Comment: This is correct. You can however use full [AspectJ via load-time weaving (LTW)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-aj-ltw) from within Spring.